# How to create user login and authentication in Sql server for two groups of users - admins and customers?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am making a mini project where we have two types of users - admins and customers using Sql server. Every user needs connection to the database , even those with invalid login credentials , so that their credentials can be validated. My query is , once every user gets connected to the database , how to grant db access only to those users whose login credentials are valid ?

Comment: sorry , my bad it's Sql server @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Login credentials are validated on the attempt of loging inot the SQL Server. If this is regarding your app internal account then single table with login and pass will do the job.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Why do you think you can connect to the database with invalid credentials and **then** check if they should be allowed to connect?

Comment: @SeanLange Are you suggesting that there be a different login credential for every user for connecting to sql server ? That doesn't make any sense. I want to store id and passwords in a table. Every user will connect to the database, regardless of whether his credentials are valid or not, so that his credentials can be validated. After that I want to grant access only to users with valid credentials.

Comment: So your user doesn't connect to the database, your application does using the same user credentials for every login. Then you validate your user against the username/password combo. IF they are validated you present the user with menu options or whatever is relevant to their role. And please don't store passwords in clear text, they be salted and hashed.

Comment: Okay. One more thing - consider a purely hypothetical scenario where user has been given the app's source code as well. Then he can run his own queries on the database. Is there some way to set permissions/roles on the db such that   admin's login credentials  give you read/write access on the database, normal user credentials give you read access and invalild credentials give you no access at all ?